# Stack Trace Console in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

Does IntelliJ have an equivalent to Eclipse's "Java Stack Trace Console," where you can paste in a stack trace and it will linkify it for you if it matches any of the source files in your project?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

⇧⌘A ->  `Analyze Stacktrace...`

The clipboard content is automatically pasted in the window, so you can just press enter.

Comment: For non-mac users: `ctrl+shift+a`.

Comment: Some fairly recent documentation @ https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/analyze-stacktrace-dialog.html

Answer (score 3):

I think it maybe possible : Look [here](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2006/08/analyzing-external-stack-traces/).

IntelliJ IDEA has a StackTrace Analyzer

> Just click Analyze Stacktrace under the Analyze menu, and copy your
>   stack trace in the dialog box. If your bug tracker or mail client
>   corrupts stack traces (cut or wrap lines, etc.), simply click
>   Normalize. - See more at:
>   http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2006/08/analyzing-external-stack-traces/#sthash.zyEcrI1b.dpuf

You can also install stack trace unscramble plugins (Zelix Klassmaster/ProGuard) to make sense of scrambled stacktraces.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, and even better than Eclipse's b/c when it opens up it automatically pulls in whatever is on your clipboard. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

It's built into the console.  When I get an exception in a JUnit test, I can click on any class in the stack trace and immediately go to the source line.  No plug-in necessary.

I use the enterprise version 10, not the community edition.

Comment: Of course, so does Eclipse. But it doesn't allow you to paste arbitrary text into it. Eclipse has a special console for this.

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/analyze-stacktrace-dialog.html) Analyze > Analyze Stacktrace