# Java Not Printing Exceptions Unless Caught

Tags: java, exception

Recently I've been developing a program using jdk 8 u 51 and I noticed my program was crashing randomly without printing any stacktraces.

Here is the example code

```
if (target > 0)
    entities[target] = null;
```

I didn't see that an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception was being thrown until I wrapped that code with

```
try {
    if (target > 0)
        entities[target] = null;
} catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

I always thought that Java would print an exception even if it is not caught.

Was this changed in jdk 8 or am I dreaming?

Thanks!

Comment: This depends entirely on context, especially for runtime exceptions.

Comment: Or unless exception has been caught somewhere else and just ignored..!!!

Comment: Sotirios could you expand on that a bit?

Comment: Are you executing this from the command line?

Comment: Owen I'm running it from intellij

Comment: Where are you running your code? In a separate thread? What's the uncaught exception handler for that thread? What's on the call stack when that code gets called? Is your exception getting swallowed/handled elsewhere?

Comment: This is in the main loop of our program which is completely single threaded.

Comment: Please provide an MCVE.

Comment: I'm not familiar with intellij. Perhaps it is consuming the exception details and you need some special operation to activate or show it. This may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716996/stack-trace-console-in-intellij-idea

Comment: Hi, It's not a problem with java. See: http://ideone.com/cuMuMw. It must be with the rest of your program or IDE specific. Additionally, given that Exception is a subclass of Throwable, what would throwable not catch?